Expected value of operation on 2 number array
I was inspired by this question, and thought of the following similar question. Consider an array of 2 positive integers $(x, y)$. An improvement operations has a $\dfrac{x}{x+y}$ chance of increasing x by 1 and a $\dfrac{y}{x+y}$ chance of decreasing y by 1. Find a formula, in $O(m)$, for the expected value of $x$ and $y$ after $m$ improvement operations.
To solve this, I tried making a possibility tree of where $(x, y)$ can go to. For example, after 1 improvement operation $(1, 3)$ can go to $(2, 3)$ or $(1, 2)$ and after $2$ improvement operations, the $(2, 3)$ can go to $(3, 3)$ or $(2, 2)$ and the $(1, 2)$ can go to $(2, 2)$ or $(1, 1)$ and this process can continue after $m $ improvement operations. The expected value of 1 and 3 after 2 improvement operations can be found by going through the tree. We get $x=(1/4)(2/5)(3)+(1/4)(3/5)(2)+(3/4)(1/3)(2)+(3/4)(2/3)(1)=1.6$ and $y=(1/4)(2/5)(3)+(1/4)(3/5)(2)+(3/4)(1/3)(2)+(3/4)(2/3)(1)=1.6$. This was my brute force attempt which obviously doesn't meet the time requirements but I also tried using dynamic programing however this gave me a polynomial time complexity, not linear. Is it even possible to get a linear time complexity?
